# How can I modify the 'Insert/edit link' option to offer root-relative urls?

Tags: urls

Using the text (not visual) editor when composing posts, I'd prefer the suggested urls to be root-relative rather than absolute.

What do I need to do to enable this?

Comment: Reasons to do something are often very important, why do you need/want/prefer relative URLs?

Comment: @cybmeta 23... because absolute is unnecessary. My image paths (I don't use the media library) are root-relative, I use a function to remove the prefix from permalinks, and on my non-WP sites I always use root-relative urls.